# What is the standard behavior when loading Managed Objects with relations in Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data

Im facing a common yet simple question when talking about Core Data.  In a simple Master-Detail example, where one Entity named "Category" has (to-many) relationship with an Entity named "Products", what would it be expected at loading time when fetching Categories?

Does the Categories load also its related products automatically? or we still have to fetch them in the Detail View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to read up on Core Data [faults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html). They provide a way for the Core Data system to give you back the object you fetched - a Category, say - without loading all the related Products immediately. Instead, the `products` relationship will contain a *fault* - effectively a promise to give you real Product instances when you need them.

Later, when you go to access the Category's `products` relationship, Core Data will automatically and transparently load the contents of that relationship without needing you to run another fetch. This is called "realizing" or "firing" a fault, and requires no extra action on your part.